# Multiple selection in query does not return object

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

In the context of writing a forum, I am creating a page listing all the recent topics, and for each topic I'm trying to display some info about the author. The query currently involves 2 tables: User and Post.

Below is the request I use: it executes without error, but does not return the expected info because the `(SELECT ...) as author` returns a string when I would expect it returns the full User object.

```
$q = $em->createQuery("SELECT p, ( SELECT COUNT(a.id) FROM App\Entity\Post a WHERE p.id = a.parent_id ) as nb_answers,
                                 ( SELECT u FROM App\Entity\User u WHERE p.user_id = u.id) as author
                               FROM App\Entity\Post p
                               WHERE p.parent_id = 0
                               ORDER BY p.date DESC");
```

The dump of the query is (note the `string(1) "1"` near the end for author):

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    object(App\Entity\Post)#354 (7) {
      ["id":"App\Entity\Post":private]=>
      int(7)
      ["user_id":"App\Entity\Post":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["text":"App\Entity\Post":private]=>
      string(83) "Post title"
      ["title":"App\Entity\Post":private]=>
      string(29) "Post message"
      ["date":"App\Entity\Post":private]=>
      object(DateTime)#374 (3) {
        ["date"]=>
        string(26) "2020-07-25 00:00:00.000000"
        ["timezone_type"]=>
        int(3)
        ["timezone"]=>
        string(3) "UTC"
      }
      ["category_id":"App\Entity\Post":private]=>
      int(1)
      ["parent_id":"App\Entity\Post":private]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["nb_answers"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["author"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
```

Is this the expected behavior with Doctrine or I am missing something?

Comment: I am pretty sure, this doesn't work as you expect it, if you can use it, I suggest to test with ```createNativeQuery()``` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a queryBuilder ?

Answer (score 2):

Your query has this part with `(SELECT u ...)` which is a sub-query in the select part, which means it has to return a scalar (which doctrine does for you).

what you probably want is:

```
SELECT p, (...), u
FROM App\Entity\Post p
LEFT JOIN App\Entity\User u WITH p.user_id = u.id
WHERE p.parent_id = 0
ORDER BY p.date DESC
```

tbh, I'm not entirely sure if WITH is correct, maybe you need ON, maybe put the *condition* in `(...)`.

**However**, I have this feeling that you didn't properly define your entities, because your Post entity has a property `user_id` (probably of type int) instead of a property `user` (a [ManyToOne](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-bidirectional) relation). If you had, you could have just written: `SELECT p, p.user, ...`. Since you're using an ORM, why not use all the wonderful features it provides?